# Keybinds in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a key bind that will work even when I am not clicked onto the program gui or minimized. It am trying to make an auto clicker and want to be able to turn it on and off mid game without going on the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [keyboard package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard) where you can set `hotkeys` (keybinds) to run specific commands. However, it doesn't have suport for mouse yet as mentioned in the description. On the other hand, [PyHook package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook) supports keyboard and mouse so it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you it helps a lot

Comment: Glad to help! I'm curious though, is this for Blade and Soul?

Comment: No Minecraft. Lol